# IOS-Setting an image as your background

Tags: ios

Im new to IOS and I am having trouble finding out how to make the background of my app an image. Could someone help me? Thanks

Comment: Add a `UIImageView` to your main view controller.

Comment: @rmaddy Where do you put your image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to create a UIImageView, add the image to it, and add it as a subview of your view controller. I would recommend doing this in your view controller's viewDidLoad method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];

   UIImageView *backgroundImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
   [backgroundImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImageFile.png"]];
   [self.view addSubview:backgroundImageView];
}
```

Comment: In what folder do you put your image?

Comment: Shouldn't matter, although I usually create an Images folder to keep the project tidy.